# Is it possible to apply mercurial patch to a single subdir only?

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial patch listing many directories.
I want to apply the patch to only one of those directories.

So, the patch says:
  dir1/a.c
  dir1/b.c
  dir2/a.c
  dir2/b.c

I want to apply the patch to only dir1 so after the patch dir1 has the files changed but dir 2 not.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot patch partially. But after you applied the patch, you can revert selectively, so that only changes within the desired subdir remain. Thus after you patched the source (without commit), a

`hg revert --all --exclude dir1/*`

should do the trick.